# IMPORTXML in Google Sheets and XPath

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

Site address: http://www.eng.kodex.com/product_view.do?fId=2ETF68

In Google Sheets, I want to crawl prices iNAV (KRW) in the site.

I found the XPath and typed the `importxml` function in the spreadsheet, but it does not work.

> Could not parse imported XML content

XPath: `//*[@id="container"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/p[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://www.eng.kodex.com/product_view.do?fId=2ETF68")),
 "where Col1 contains 'basp:""'"), "(\d+.*)""")
```

or rounded:

```
=ROUND(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTDATA("http://www.eng.kodex.com/product_view.do?fId=2ETF68")),
 "where Col1 contains 'basp:""'"), "(\d+.*)"""))
```

[image: 0]