# IMPORTDATA in Google Sheets and XPath

Tags: regex, google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula

On GoogleSheet I need to crawl the Amazon's share's price (following xPath) on this page : https://www.boursorama.com/cours/AMZN/

```
//*[@id="main-content"]/div/section[1]/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]
```

**I can do it** using this formula and it works :

```
IMPORTXML("https://www.boursorama.com/cours/AMZN/", "//*[@id=""main-content""]/div/section[1]/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]")
```

**BUT** there is a daily limitation of IMPORTXML function.

**So to avoid this Google's daily limitation** I need to use [this elegant method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56278362/importxml-in-google-sheets-and-xpath) so it should be something like this :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.boursorama.com/cours/AMZN/"));
 "where Col1 contains 'basp:""'");"(\d+.*)""") <-- here is the line where something is wrong
```

**I'm not used to** work with REGEX, does someone can help me on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.boursorama.com/cours/AMZN")),
 "where Col1 contains 'data-ist-bid-price>'", 0), 
 "</?\S+[^<>]*>", )*1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, ok great you made this function work, I didn't know about FLATTEN function.
I edit your code because it targetted the wrong data. so now it target to :
=substitute(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(G3)); "where Col1 contains 'c-instrument c-instrument--last"" data-ist-last'"; 0); "</?\S+[^<>]*>"; );".";",") BUT it get two numeric values insteed of one. The first value is the one I need. The second one always start with a "-" or a "+" symbol. I'm not a big head of REGEX. So do know how to get only the text BEFORE the "+" or "-" symbol ? Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: @Arnaud try:  `=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(G3)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'c-instrument c-instrument--last"" data-ist-last'", 0), 
 "</?\S+[^<>]*>", ),".",","), "^\d+(?:.\d+)?")`

Comment: hi ! Thanks ! It's so much better that the Mc Gyver way I found yesterday ! Thank you so much, I own you a beer (I mean a coffee !)